# The proper way to delay my jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have coded a sale "pop-up" window to appear on my product pages, as well as a "mask" that appears behind the pop-up to dim the page content behind the pop-up.

Both of these elements are displayed using the following code

```
    <div id="boxes">
        <div id="dialog" class="window">
            <div class="close"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="mask"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-content">
       <a class="show-box"></a>
    </div>

    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() {  

        var id = '#dialog';

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set heigth and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});
        $('#mask').delay( 7000 );
        //transition effect
        $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.5);  

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).delay( 7000 );  
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);     

        //if close button is clicked
        $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#mask').hide();
        $('.window').hide();
        });

        //if mask is clicked
        $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
        });
        //toggle view link 
        $('#show-box').click(function () {
        $('#mask').fadeIn(500); 
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.5);
        $('.window').fadeIn(500);   
        $('.window').show();
        });  

        });
      </script>
```

Originally, the script instantly loaded the pop-up window on document.ready. I added the `$('#mask').delay( 7000 );` and the `$(id).delay( 7000 );` to wait 7 seconds before displaying the pop-up.

This works great, with one snafu. During the 7 seconds of delay time, all hover functionality of the page is lost. The mask itself does have a fixed position covering the entire screen, so it's as if the mask element is loaded, even though it is not displayed during the 7 seconds.

How would I properly delay the pop-up and mask a full 7 seconds, while not breaking hover functionality of the page during that time?

Comment: How about a setTimeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply use `setTimeout`. Create a function that handles everything after the click, so you can bundle it efficiently and call the function in settimeout.

```
function delayedFadeIn(){
    //place the code you wish to be delayed here
    ...
}
```

(...)

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    var id = '#dialog';

    //Get the screen height and width
    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    setTimeout(delayedFadeIn, 7000);
    (...)
}
```

Comment: @AlexRitter sorry about that, I've removed what I guessed it did. You'd just fill in what you need to in the delayedFadeIn function and happiness can ensue.

Comment: If I understand this right from looking at it, the function delayedFadeIn would only activate after a user clicks the #show-box. Correct? Is it possible to add the setTimeout to the page load, as the pop-up is automatically displayed on page load?

Comment: @AlexRitter that is correct. For it to be added on page load you would do ` setTimeout(fn, 7000) ` within the  ` $(document).ready(function() { ... } `, that would work.

Comment: could you possibly edit your answer to include this functionality? I have only a basic jquery understanding, and I'm not sure of the syntax in adding that line.

Comment: bam. happiness ensues!